# Не получается распарсить ответ JSON в объект С#

Tags: c#, .net, json

С сервера приходит ответ такого вида

```
{
    "Entries": {
        "Entry": [
            {
                "REGION_ID": "12",
                "CITY_EN": "Svitlovodsk",
                "CITYTYPE_RU": "Город",
                "DISTRICT_ID": "199",
                "REGION_RU": "Кировоградская",
                "CITY_RU": "Светловодск",
                "NAME_UA": "Активний запис",
                "DISTRICT_EN": "Svitlovodskyi",
                "REGION_UA": "Кіровоградська",
                "OLDCITY_EN": null,
                "SHORTCITYTYPE_RU": null,
                "REGION_EN": "Kirovohradska",
                "CITY_ID": "5155",
                "DISTRICT_UA": "Світловодський",
                "OLDCITY_RU": null,
                "SHORTCITYTYPE_EN": null,
                "CITYTYPE_EN": "City",
                "SHORTCITYTYPE_UA": "м",
                "CITY_UA": "Світловодськ",
                "OWNOF": null,
                "CITYTYPE_UA": "Місто",
                "OLDCITY_UA": null,
                "DISTRICT_RU": "Светловодск"
            },
            {
                "REGION_ID": "20",
                "CITY_EN": "Svitlovshchyna",
                "CITYTYPE_RU": "Село",
                "DISTRICT_ID": "449",
                "REGION_RU": "Харьковская",
                "CITY_RU": "Светловщина",
                "NAME_UA": "Активний запис",
                "DISTRICT_EN": "Lozivskyi",
                "REGION_UA": "Харківська",
                "OLDCITY_EN": null,
                "SHORTCITYTYPE_RU": null,
                "REGION_EN": "Kharkivska",
                "CITY_ID": "22538",
                "DISTRICT_UA": "Лозівський",
                "OLDCITY_RU": null,
                "SHORTCITYTYPE_EN": null,
                "CITYTYPE_EN": "Village",
                "SHORTCITYTYPE_UA": "с",
                "CITY_UA": "Світловщина",
                "OWNOF": null,
                "CITYTYPE_UA": "Село",
                "OLDCITY_UA": null,
                "DISTRICT_RU": "Лозовской"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Мне нужно распарсить его в объект JsonUkrPoshtaResponse, классы приведены ниже

```
public class JsonUkrPoshtaResponse : IJsonUkrPoshtaResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("Entries")]
        public IEntries Entries { get; set; }
    }

    public class Entries : IEntries
    {
        [JsonProperty("Entry")]
        public List <IEntry> Entry { get; set; }
    }

    public class Entry : IEntry
    {
        //attributes for cities
        [JsonProperty("REGION_ID")]
        public string RegionId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("CITY_EN")]
        public string CityEn { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("CITYTYPE_RU")]
        public string CityTypeRu { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("DISTRICT_ID")]
        public string DistrictId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("REGION_RU")]
        public string RegionRu { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("CITY_RU")]
        public string CityRu { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("NAME_UA")]
        public string NameUa { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("DISTRICT_EN")]
        public string DistrictEn { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("REGION_UA")]
        public string RegionUa { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("OLDCITY_EN")]
        public object OldCityEn { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("SHORTCITYTYPE_RU")]
        public object ShortCityTypeRu { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("REGION_EN")]
        public string RegionEn { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("CITY_ID")]
        public string CityId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("DISTRICT_UA")]
        public string DistrictUa { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("OLDCITY_RU")]
        public object OldCityRu { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("SHORTCITYTYPE_EN")]
        public object ShortCityTypeEn { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("CITYTYPE_EN")]
        public string CityTypeEn { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("SHORTCITYTYPE_UA")]
        public string ShortCityTypeUa { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("CITY_UA")]
        public string CityUa { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("OWNOF")]
        public object Ownof { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("CITYTYPE_UA")]
        public string CityTypeUa { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("OLDCITY_UA")]
        public object OldCityUa { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("DISTRICT_RU")]
        public string DistrictRu { get; set; }
}
  }
```

Метод передает url с запросом методу базового класса, в котором ответ приходит, но приложение застревает на строке  `var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);` и все. Ошибку не виводит, просто ничего не происходит. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

```
 public async Task<List<ICity>> GetCitiesAsync()
        {
            var url = $"{baseUrl}get_city_by_region_id_and_district_id_and_city_ua?district_id=&region_id=&city_ua=Світло";
            var responseTask = await baseApiService.GetItemAsync<JsonUkrPoshtaResponse>(url);
            List<ICity> result = ReturnCities(responseTask);
            return result;
        }

public async Task<T> GetItemAsync<T>(string url)
        {
            var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);
                return item;
            }
             throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
```

Comment: объекты чего парсер должен создать вот тут `public object OldCityEn { get; set; }` ?

Comment: @tym32167, по-идее, тут должна быть строка (старое название города на англ.), но в почти всегда значение в ответе null, поэтому был выбран тип object. Ранее все свойства имели тип string, но результата также не было.

Comment: Если там строка или ничего, то оставьте string

Comment: И что находится в `item`? Код не может "заснуть" в этом месте...